# How to fix "Directory not empty" on move during docker build?

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, dockerfile, yarnpkg

I have a working Dockerfile for a node application:

```
FROM node:8.8
ENV TERM=xterm-color NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=warn PATH="$PATH:/usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin/"
VOLUME ["/logs"]
WORKDIR /tmp/node
ADD package.json yarn.lock .npmrc ./
RUN yarn install --frozen-lockfile --ignore-platform --ignore-engines --quiet
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
ADD . /usr/src/app
RUN mv /tmp/node/* ./ && tsc && webpack
CMD ["node", "/usr/src/app/server"]
```

I wanted to re-created the caching behavior for the `node_modules` during build, hence I have updated the Dockerfile for another project to look very similar.

```
FROM node:9-alpine
WORKDIR /tmp/node
ADD package.json yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn install --frozen-lockfile --ignore-platform --ignore-engines --quiet

WORKDIR /app
ADD . /app/
RUN mv /tmp/node/* ./

EXPOSE 1337

CMD ["yarn", "start"]
```

Yet for that Dockerfile I get an unexpected error during:

```
$ docker build .
...
Step 7/9 : RUN mv /tmp/node/* ./
 ---> Running in 51543827cd89
mv: can't rename '/tmp/node/node_modules': Directory not empty
The command '/bin/sh -c mv /tmp/node/* ./' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Why doesn't the `mv` command work here?

Answer (score 1):

When you run `docker build .`, the current directory gets passed as its context. It's most likely the case that you have either run the `yarn install` command on your host already which is why you alrady have a

```
/app/node_modules
```

This is why it cannot be moved, as it already exists.

To avoid passing the folder along within the context, you can add:

```
node_modules/
```

in your `.dockerignore` file.